# Bookmarklet works on one page but not another

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

I have this this tinyurl bookmarklet (I had to add X to this to get past the SE blocker ... curious why bit.ly was not blocked above):

```
javascript:void(location.href='httpXs://tinXyurl.com/create.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href))
```

It works on:

```
https://play.google.com
```

But does *not* work on:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging
```

Why? Is the page blocking this somehow, and if so, why would it ever need to do that?

I'm asking on stackoverflow, and not on webapps.stackexchange.com, as I suspect this is a browser specific problem.

Browser version:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0
```

### Update #1

Verified as working on Chrome: Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

### Update #2

Found a bug report in Firefox at [Bug 866522](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522) that might or might not be the root cause.

### Update #3

Inside [Bug 866522](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522) at [Comment 28](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522#c28) refers to `security.csp.enable` to false in `about:config`. I did that in my Firefox, and the bookmarklet started to work. Whether or not that is a viable workaround, remains to be determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two extra X's in your bookmarklet: `httpXs` and `tinXyurl.com` (should be `https` and `tinyurl.com`). I'm guessing you added them because StackOverflow blocks tinyurl.com create URLs.

I tried the bookmarklet without the extra X's in Chrome and it worked flawlessly with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging. The problem might be with your version of FireFox.

Comment: "I'm guessing you added them ..." : Read the description where I stated "I had to add X to this to get past the SE blocker ... ".

Comment: "the extra X's in Chrome": I'll try Chrome and update my question with the result.

Comment: Added Update #1 and #2 to my post. #2 is likely the cause, and I need to verify that with some experimentation, and report back.

Comment: Added Update #3 to my post to indicate the workaround I found. Thus, your statement "The problem might be with your version of FireFox" is spot on. Marking as the answer for now.